# SQLite database file corruption in Unity

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Hi I am using SQLite as database in my Unity project. For some reason database file got corrupted but luckily I had backup so I didn't lose anything. I think the reason behind corruption was using unity collab to share database file. My question is what can I do not to corrupt the file again? Also can it corrupt after releasing the game in player's local gamefiles?

And here is the static methods i am using to execute commands, maybe something is wrong with it.

```
public static void Execute(string command, ref DataTable datatable)
{
    string dbPath = ("Data Source=" + Application.dataPath + "/database.s3db");
    using (SqliteConnection cnt = new SqliteConnection(dbPath))
    {
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(command, cnt))
        {
            using (SqliteDataAdapter adapter = new SqliteDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(datatable);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void Execute(string command)
{
    string dbPath = ("Data Source=" + Application.dataPath + "/database.s3db");
    using (SqliteConnection cnt = new SqliteConnection(dbPath))
    {
        using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(command, cnt))
        {
            cnt.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnt.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just few questions: 1.How did you know it was corrupted? 2.What happened after it got corrupted? 3.Is the corrupted data create through code after build or in the Editor? 4.Where did you put the corrupted data in the Editor?

Comment: @Programmer I wasn't working on project for a few days and then I updated unity files to the files published by my friend. Then I got the error "The database disk image is malformed" at console in game when an interaction happened and a sqlite command executed through given code. Then I just replaced corrupted sqlite database file with a backup file.

Comment: [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)

Comment: Note: it is inefficient to re-open the database for every command; consider using a single connection for the entire program.

Comment: @CL. I didn't mind that because I don't have much data on database and it is pretty fast even while openning it for every command but I will try to change that, thanks! Should I use singleton pattern in my connection class?

Comment: Whatever makes sense in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite implements [atomic transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html), but those guarantees hold only as long as the database file is accessed only through the SQLite library.

In your case, it's likely that the database file was copied from your friend's computer in the middle of a transaction, i.e., some changes did not end up in the published version. The only way to avoid this is to ensure that no files are currently being modified when doing the publishing.

Comment: We will be more careful now! I also enabled WAL, it should make database file more resistant to corruption, right? My main concern is that can it happen again after game relase in player's local game files?

Comment: For this case, there is no difference between rollback journal mode and WAL mode. Why do you think that the player's local files will be accessed by Unity Collab *while the game is running*?

Comment: I don't think Unity Collab can do that. I actually don't even think it will happen after relase. While we were searching why our file was corrupted, we found an article about how a developer handled corruption in his application on customer side. Now we are just afraid that if it can happen in our game on player side. It would be horrible to lose playerdata and also game would not run until we change database file.

Comment: There are other reasons why the DB might become corrupt (see MikeT's comment); if you want to keep the player's data safe, make backups. Also consider separate databases for read-only assets and player data.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I will definetly seperate my databases. One last question to sum up. It is safe to use SQLite in our unity project to save datas as long as we are careful, right? Thanks for all your effort.

Comment: Safe compared to what? Writing it directly to a file without transactions? Not storing the data at all?

Comment: Alternative to saving player data might be serializing into JSON but then I don't know how should I store long read-only texts like dialogues and we have something like in game wiki and their body texts. Using SQLite makes it so easy to read, update them for non-experienced developers like us.